# How do I create a new task under a specific user with Prisma?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

I want to be able to add tasks underneath each user then so I can then only fetch them for that specific user.
I don't understand how to initiate a prisma create action that links the current user and the tasks data together in mongodb.
Before trying to link them together I was able to create tasks in their own document.

prisma.schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id    String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email String @unique
  name String
  password String
  tasks Task[]
}

model Task {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title String @unique
  author   User   @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [email])
  authorId String  // relation scalar field (used in the `@relation` attribute above)
}
```

action:

```
export async function createTask(title, user: string) {
/* user prop is currently the logged in email as a string */
  "use server";
  try {
    const task = await prisma.task.create({
      data: {
        title: title,
      }
    });
    revalidatePath("/");
    return task;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof Prisma.PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
      console.log(`Prisma error message: ${e.message}`)
      console.log(`Prisma error code: ${e.code}`)
    }
    else {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `data: { author: { connect: { id } } }` is well documented https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations